# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

when i try to run this function it gives me this error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment' can any one help me please

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        file_url = photos.url(filename)
        with io.open(filename, 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()
        image = types.Image(content=content)
        response = vision_client.label_detection(image=image)
        labels = response.label_annotations()

    return render_template('index.html', thelabels=labels)
```

Comment: If the if statement is not true, `labels` does not get assigned a value. Try setting `labels` to a default value before the if statement.

Comment: it gives jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `labels` variable in your function is only instantiated if the `if` statement returns `True`, otherwise the variable never gets created.

You need to set up an `else` statement to create the variable if the initial check doesn't return `True` (or give `labels` a default value before the `if` statement, as suggested by Ahmad):

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    # Option 1: give `labels` a default value here - Doesn't have to be `None`
    labels = None
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        file_url = photos.url(filename)
        with io.open(filename, 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()
        image = types.Image(content=content)
        response = vision_client.label_detection(image=image)
        labels = response.label_annotations()

    else: # Option 2: set `labels` to `None` in an `else` statement in case the `if` statement check returns False
        labels = None

    return render_template('index.html', thelabels=labels)
```

Comment: it gives jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

Comment: There are no `}` characters anywhere in the code above which leads me to believe that this error is originating from somewhere else in what I'm assuming is your Flask code. Furthermore, the name of the exception (`TemplateSyntaxError`) suggests you have a typo (a missing `:` character) in one of your template files. I suggest you read up on Jinja2 templating to get an idea of where the error might be coming from.

Answer (score -1):

the localbound error is caused because the variable`labels` is defined inside the `if` statement. define it inside the function

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    labels = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        file_url = photos.url(filename)
        with io.open(filename, 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()
        image = types.Image(content=content)
        response = vision_client.label_detection(image=image)
        labels = response.label_annotations()
    return render_template('index.html', thelabels=labels)
```

> when you render the template check whether `thelabels` is `''` or not inside the template

hope it helps

Comment: it gives jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

Comment: try the edited one. the error was because you copied and pasted the code without indentation. Sorry i carelessly posted it without proper indentation